# Create a loop to count 0-6 for 100 time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to make a loop to fill a list with values ranging from 0 to 6 for 100 times.
i tired it like this but i seems like it it multiply it self 100*6

```
ls = []
x = 0
i = 0
y = 0

while x != 10:
    for i in range (1,7):
        ls.append(i)
        x +=1
 
print(ls)
```

Does anybody knows any solution to this. Thanks in advance. If anyone also knows a solution in pandas that would also be great!!

Comment: Random values  between 0 and 6? Or just 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1 etc.

Comment: you are adding +1 to x in loop of 7 so your x will aways overflow your condition x!=10 instead of x!=10 write x <= 10

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop:

```
N = 6
lst = list(range(N+1))*100
```

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)/[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 6

a = np.tile(np.arange(N+1), 100)

s = pd.Series(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `range`.

```
>>> list(range(7))*100
```

Or you can use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.tile(np.arange(7), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6] * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = list(range(1, 7)) * 100
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...
```

for a total length of 600 items.

If you want 100 items, generate a bit less, and cut the list:

```
ls = (list(range(1, 7)) * (100 // 6 + 1))[:100]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
LIST_TO_REPEAT = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
REPEAT_AMOUNT = 100

array = []

for i in range(0, REPEAT_AMOUNT):
    array = array + LIST_TO_REPEAT
    
print(array)
```

This adds the list to LIST_TO_REPEAT to array REPEAT_AMOUNT  amount of times

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = [i for _ in range(100) for i in range(0, 7)]
print(ls)
```